# Did God show lenience to King Uzziah in 2 Chronicles 26:16-19?

Tags: leviticus, 2-chronicles

(KJV) 2 Chronicles 26:16-19

> 16 But when he was strong, his heart was lifted up to his destruction:  for he transgressed against the LORD his God, and went into the temple of the LORD to burn incense upon the altar of incense.   17 And Azariah the priest went in after him, and with him fourscore priests of the LORD, that were valiant men:  18 And they withstood Uzziah the king, and said unto him, It appertaineth not unto thee, Uzziah, to burn incense unto the LORD, but to the priests the sons of Aaron, that are consecrated to burn incense:  go out of the sanctuary;  for thou hast trespassed;  neither shall it be for thine honour from the LORD God.   19 Then Uzziah was wroth, and had a censer in his hand to burn incense:  and while he was wroth with the priests, the ***leprosy*** even rose up in his forehead before the priests in the house of the LORD, from beside the incense altar.

(KJV) Leviticus 10:1-2

> 1 And Nadab and Abihu, the sons of Aaron, took either of them his censer, and put fire therein, and put incense thereon, and offered strange fire before the LORD, which he commanded them not.   2 And there went out fire from the LORD, and devoured them, and they ***died*** before the LORD

Emphasis added.

In the above texts it seems King Uzziah committed a similar offense to Nadab & Abihu but was not punished like the sons of Aaron.

Did God show lenience to Uzziah?

Answer (score 1):

In Leviticus 10, God was setting up the order of the newly established priesthood. He was being strict in punishing Nadab and Abihu
to set an example.

Similarly, God was establishing the nascent church in Acts 5. Ananias and Sapphira were killed for lying to the Holy Spirit to set an example for the church order.

> 11 Great fear seized the whole church and all who heard about these events.

It sent a message of deterrence.

Did God show lenience to Uzziah?

Yes, in fact, God is lenient to all of us. God does not punish us for what we deserve.

Answer (score 0):

Did God show lenience to King Uzziah in 2 Chronicles 26:16-19?
Did God show leniency to Uzziah?

---

God is no respecter of persons.

He does what he does so "Isa 43:10 ... that ye may know and believe me, and understand that I [am] he: before me there was no God formed, neither shall there be after me."

The key here is in the embedded metaphor. Fire is a symbol of the Spirit, so strange fire symbolized going after strange gods.

But Uzziah became a prophecy of Christ. He was righteous, then entered the temple (as Christ became the burnt offering) he was made to be sin (covered with leprosy). He did not die from his leprosy, but was renamed Azariah (the name of the priest) (See 2 Kings 15) to indicate that Christ in resurrection would be our high priest. Jesus was the heir to the literal throne in Israel (king) who became the priest.

Comment: Am baffled why this has a -1. +1 to undo.